# AWS elastic beanstalk is not getting the environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I'm trying to run a Rails 6 app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I get from puma log the following (repeats every few seconds)

> [21776] + Gemfile in context: /var/app/current/Gemfile 
> [21776] Early termination of worker

The version numbers:

- Rails `6.0.3.3`
- puma `4.3.5`
- ElasticBeanstalk `Ruby 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.1`
- ruby `2.7.1p83`

The server is unresponsive from outside the instance, and there's nothing on `log/production.log`.

Running on a dev machine on `production` mode there's no errors, and the database is reachable (no migration failure).

Running on the AWS instance the command `bundle exec puma -p 3000 -e production` I get

```sh
Puma starting in single mode...
Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.7.1-p83), codename: Mysterious Traveller
Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
Environment: production
Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

so there's no obvious error that may cause the worker to halt.

How can I find out what's causing the workers to fail?

**Edit 1:**

I ran Rails console on the instance and found that the environment variables are missing - e.g. the production database user/pass/host. Once I hardcoded them I could connect to the database.
I suspect the absence of other environment variables is making the app crash.

Comment: I do not think that EB uses port 3000 -- I would instead use $PORT environment variable. You might also need to check where the nginx instance is looking for your backend to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user on AWS forum had [the answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=957547).

Setting in my Gemfile

```rb
gem "nio4r", "= 2.5.2"
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this! I wonder how we avoid something like this happening again in future?

Comment: @SimonL.Brazell AWS support recommend taking a separate branch and creating a parallel EB environment with the latest platform configuration and see if it works. They also said that they don't even have ssh access to the box so it's up to you to spot these problems.

Comment: but this happened to me without a deployment or anything, only the client noticed that the server was no longer responding and let me know, surely if the server isn't changing / disturbed it should just continue working right?

Comment: same happened to me: the box kept running as if nothing happened but the rails app wasn't responding. I detected the problem by elimination and found that puma was spawning workers and they kept dying.

Comment: I found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/locally-packaging-gem-dependencies-for-ruby-applications-in-elastic-beanstalk/) detailing how to package gems with your application, not sure if this would solve the problem but I might give it a try.